# angular.min.js not detected by html script file

Tags: angularjs, html

I recently started with angular.

1. Do I always have to be connected to the internet to run tutorial scripts too?(bcoz I'm running offline)
2. I downloaded the angular.min.is file from the angular website and saved it on my system.
   Included this path in the HTML script as `<script src="C:/.../..../../angular.min.js"></script>`

But this did not work because when I run the html script , I get only the html output which means angular.min.js is not detected by the html.
Double checked the path for typos, etc. All good.
What else do I need to install to get this working?

Comment: Angular.js will stop support in around 3 years, you shouldn't start a new project with it. Consider using angular (>=5) instead.

Comment: @Supamiu Thanks ,will do, but how do I get my HTML to read the angular.min.js file?

Comment: What is the error in console?

Comment: Have you checked the console? I don't see how this would work properly, also, using an absolute path isn't recommended as you'll have to change it once in production.

Comment: @ivp I do not see any error msg, though I get the HTML page (output) according to HTML script. Also in the HTML script , the ng -tags don't change color(keyword colours).

Comment: Check out my answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Change the **'...'** with the actual folder names.

```
<script src="file:///C:/.../..../../angular.min.js"></script>
```

E.g:

```
<script src="file:///C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already have the absolute path mentioned in the <script> tag. The '....' Is only for representation purpose here as I'm not sure if readers would be interested in reading all folder names. You get the point.

Comment: I know that. Notice the this part in the script tag. This is important ---> file:///

Comment: Can you inspect and try to open the scr value into into new tab? If it opens, the script is loaded.

Comment: when i open angular.min.js with the path mentioned in a new tab, it does show me the script file. But html script still does not detect it.

Comment: If you see the code in new tab...then it is loaded properly. There is a error in your angular code :(